# Ao chamar uma função assíncrona, é também necessário anotar a função chamadora como "async"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, assincronismo

Tenho uma dúvida sobre funções assíncronas. Tenho a seguinte função no meu arquivo de *models*:

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
    código qualquer aqui...
};
```

E agora preciso chamar esta função no meu arquivo de controller, em uma nova função, por exemplo:

```
const loginController = async  (req, res) => {
     // veja que estou chamando a primeira função aqui
     await login.create()
};
```

Minha dúvida é: faz sentido usar o `async` na função `loginController` para chamar a função `login`, ou não faz diferença? Isso atrapalha em algo no funcionamento da função `login`?

Comment: A pergunta não ficou muito clara para mim (tente [editá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/475246/edit)!)... :) Você tá perguntando se seria necessário usar o `async` na função `loginController`? Se for isso, sim, é obrigatório, já que usar `await` dentro de uma função que não está anotada como `async` evoca um `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Na verdade estou perguntando se devido a função *login* ser assíncrona, a função *loginController* também deva ser, ou posso deixá-la como uma função comum(síncrona).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JavaScript, não importa se você está usando *callbacks*, [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/)s ou funções assíncronas (que são, basicamente açúcar sintático para a API das promessas), o assincronismo é como se fosse uma "praga".

Isso significa que, sempre que você utiliza alguma API dotada de assincronismo, o restante do código que utilizou a função será obrigado a arcar com isso, tornando-se, por consequência, assíncrono também. É como se fosse uma contaminação.

Não veja isso como ruim por ser uma "contaminação", é apenas uma consequência da natureza assíncrona da linguagem.

Portanto, se você tem uma função assíncrona (como a função `login`):

```js
// Note que a função abaixo é assíncrona (`async`):
async function login(email, password) {
  // Código qualquer aqui...
};
```

Qualquer função que chamar `login` há de lidar com sua natureza assíncrona. E qualquer função que chamar a função que chamou `login` também... É, evidentemente, uma "contaminação" sem fim para cima (em direção à *call stack*):

Uma forma de lidar com esse assincronismo é utilizar o `async` e aguardar a resolução da promessa que `login` retorna utilizando o operador `await`. Assim:

```js
async function loginController(req, res) {
  // Estamos lidando com o assincronismo de `login` utilizando `await`.
  // Note que, para utilizar o `await`, você é *obrigado* a utilizar o `async`.
  const loggedIn = await login(email, password);

  if (loggedIn) {
    res.send('OK!');
  } else {
    res.send('Dados incorretos.');
  }
}
```

Uma outra opção é lidar com a promessa diretamente utilizando o método [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```js
function loginController(req, res) {
  login(email, password).then((loggedIn) => {
    if (loggedIn) {
      res.send('OK!');
    } else {
      res.send('Dados incorretos.');
    }
  });
}
```

Note que, no caso acima, não usamos `async` na função chamadora, mas lidamos com o assincronismo de `login` de forma um pouco mais explícita utilizando diretamente a API das promessas.

Um exemplo um pouco mais completo de como lidar com a API de promessas diretamente:

```js
async function a() {
  await delay(500);
  return 1;
}

// Podemos lidar com o assincronismo sem o `async`. Por exemplo:
function b() {
  // Note que a `Promise` deve ser retornada:
  return a().then((a) => a + 1);
}
 
// Nada impede de usar o `async` depois também:
async function c() {
  const result = await b();
  console.log('Resultado:', result);
}

c().then(() => console.log('Finalizado.'));

// Ignore (só para criar um efeito de "lentidão"):
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, t));
}
```

Em suma, você não é "obrigado" a usar o `async`. No entanto, você deve lidar com o assincronismo. Para isso, pode-se utilizar o `async`, a API das `Promise`s diretamente, etc.