# Como retornar o valor de uma função que utiliza promessas em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises, fetch

Eu tenho uma função que deveria checar se um usuário está inscrito no Stripe. Para isso é feita uma requisição para um servidor terceiro que retorna um array de usuários.

Quando eu faço a requisição, uma promessa é retornada: `Promise {state: 'pending'}`. Para resolver isso eu fiz o seguinte:

```js
fetch(url, { method: 'POST' }).then(async (res) => {
  await res.json()
  // Código executa perfeitamente como desejado dentro desse bloco...
});
```

Porém, isso cria um problema: Como o `fetch` está envolvido em uma função (`function M() { fetch(...) }`) e não é possível retirar o valor de dentro da promessa sem um `then`, como faço para que `M` retorne a resposta do `fetch`?

Meu código completo:

```js
checkUserSubscription: (email) => {
        var response ={status: 'inactive'}
        
        const costumers = fetch(`url/payment/list`, {method: 'POST'})
        .then(async(res) => {
           let costumers = await res.json()
           return costumers
        })
        console.log(costumers) //Promise {state: 'pending}, mas com fullfiled e value
        for (var costumer in costumers) {
            if (costumers[costumer].email == email) {
                response = {
                    email: email,
                    id: costumers[costumer].id,
                    status: 'active'
                }                
            }
        }

        return response // {status: 'inactive'}
    }
```

Resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vale acrescentar que a Promise retornada não é acessível, por exemplo em: `essaPromise.value`

Comment: Não lute contra a natureza assíncrona do JavaScript, é uma guerra que estará sempre fadada ao fracasso. Ao invés disso, abrace o assincronismo da linguagem. Nesse caso, isso significa que a sua função `M` (por exemplo) deve **retornar** a promessa (ou uma nova promessa, derivada daquela originada no `fetch`).

Comment: @LuizFelipe eu não estou tentando lutar, apenas fique um pouco confuso pois já lidei com fetch, mas isso nunca tinha acontecido antes. Você poderia deixar mais claro através de código o que você quer dizer?

Comment: Sua função `checkUserSubscription` é que deveria ser `async` e então, você espera (await) que a promise retornada no fetch seja resolvida. Sem muitos detalhes:

checkUserSubscription: async () => {  /* ... */ customers = await fetch().then(res => res.json))

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior  Vou tentar isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme disse nesta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475255/69296), o JavaScript possui uma natureza intrinsecamente assíncrona. Além disso, uma vez que uma função trabalha com alguma operação assíncrona, o *chamador* da função *precisa* se adequar ao assincronismo também.

Essa adequação do chamador pode ocorrer de duas formas principais:

- [*Callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/69296), que é o modo antigo de lidar com assincronismo no JavaScript;
- Promessa, que é o modo recomendado de se lidar com assincronismo em código JavaScript atual.

Tratarei nessa resposta exclusivamente sobre promessas, mas ideias similares podem ser aplicadas com *callbacks*.

---

Uma vez que uma função que realiza operação assincrona em JavaScript é chamada, o chamador precisa lidar com o assincronismo. E isso, tendo em vista que operações assíncronas demandam tempo para serem resolvidas, implica que o código chamador precisa "aguardar" pela conclusão da operação.

No caso de promessas, isso é feito com o `then`.

No caso de você implementar uma função que utiliza operação assíncrona e garantir que o chamador da sua função também *espere* pela conclusão do processo, você deve *retornar* a promessa. Não adianta tentar "remover o valor de uma promessa", porque isso não é possível (de forma a evitar *gambiarras*). Discuto mais sobre isso em [Como atribuir o resultado de uma promise a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/379212/69296).

O que você precisa fazer é **retornar** a promessa. Desse modo, o código que chamar a sua função poderá utilizar o `then` (ou `await`, se for função assíncrona) para *aguardar* pela resolução da *sua* função.

Abaixo deixo um exemplo para demonstrar:

```js
// Função que chama a API do GitHub para determinar
// o número de repositórios públicos de um usuário.
function getRepoCount(username) {
  const promise = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      return `O usuário ${json.login} tem ${json.public_repos} repositório(s).`;
    });
    
  // Note que eu estou retornando a promessa.
  // Assim, quem chamar esta função poderá utilizar o `then` (ou `catch`) na promessa que retornamos.
  return promise;
}

// Função que chama:
function main() {
  getRepoCount('lffg')
    .then((message) => console.log('Mensagem recebida: ' + message))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Whoops! Algo deu errado!: ' + error.message));
}

main();
```

Note, no código acima, que a função `getRepoCount` que implementei realiza operação assíncrona. Desse modo, como podemos fazer para que aqueles que *chamarem* `getRepoCount` estejam cientes de quando a operação tiver sido completa? A resposta é: **Retornando a promessa!**

Assim, você garante que todos os chamadores da função possam lidar com a promessa, o que significa aguardar a resolução (`Promise.prototype.then`) ou lidar com eventuais erros (`Promise.prototype.catch` ou segundo argumento de `then`). :)

---

No seu caso (e com algumas melhorias no código), ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
function checkUserSubscription(email) {
  return fetch(`url/payment/list`, { method: 'POST' })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((costumers) => {
      // Note que, de dentro da promessa, podemos retornar qualquer valor.
      // Nesse caso, estamos retornando o resultado da operação
      // `Array.prototype.find`, que, neste caso, irá procurar, dentro do array
      // `customers`, o usuário com o e-mail fornecido.
      //
      // O valor que retornamos de dentro dessa promessa será passado para a
      // promessa que a função `checkUserSubscription` retorna.
      return costumers.find((customer) => customer.email === email);
    });
};

checkUserSubscription('foo@provider.com')
  .then((customer) => {
    // `customer` será o objeto de `customers` referente ao e-mail.
    // Caso não existir o usuário com o e-mail fornecido no array, `customer`
    // será `undefined`. Esse comportamento se deve ao `Array.prototype.find`.
    console.log(customer);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Trate o eventual erro.
  });
```

E, claro, pode utilizar funções assíncronas para simplificar um pouco:

```js
async function checkUserSubscription(email) {
  const response = await fetch(`url/payment/list`, { method: 'POST' });
  const costumers = await response.json();

  // Pode parecer que estamos retornando "somente" o consumidor a ser encontrado,
  // mas, na verdade, estamos retornando uma promessa. Isso ocorre porque,
  // implicitamente, TODA função assincrona retorna uma promessa.
  //
  // E, como dito acima, o que precisa ser feito para que o chamador esteja
  // "ciente" do assincronismo da função que chamou é RETORNAR A PROMESSA.
  return costumers.find((customer) => customer.email === email);
}

// Note que nada muda na interface do chamador. Funções assíncronas são,
// basicamente, açúcar sintático para operações comuns relacionadas a promessas.
checkUserSubscription('foo@provider.com')
  .then((customer) => {
    console.log(customer);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Trate o eventual erro.
  });
```

Como sugestão, procure entender profundamente sobre promessas, que são essenciais para o domínio do JavaScript. Além disso, saber sobre funções assíncronas pode também ser útil. Recomendo:

- [JavaScript Promises: An introduction](https://web.dev/promises/) — é inglês, mas um excelente recurso.
- [Usando promises.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usando_promises)
- [Funções assíncronas - simplificando promessas.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu acabei identificando o erro mais tarde, mas, mesmo assim, sua resposta foi esclarecedora.