# Como faço para retornar o valor dentro de um .then em Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Sou novato em Vue e Firebase, tenho o seguinte problema: Quero retornar o valor gerado dentro do then, no console.log que está dentro do then retorna o id que foi gerado, porém, quando eu referencio o mesmo id fora do then eu recebo um undefined.

```
  enviarDados(){
    db.collection('teste').add(this.user)
    
    .then((docRef) => {
        this.idGerado = docRef.id
        console.log('Meu id:', this.idGerado)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    }); 

    console.log(this.idGerado)

  }
```

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/493351/como-retornar-o-valor-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-utiliza-promessas-em-javascript/493359#493359)

Comment: Existem bastante duplicada dessa pergunta aqui no site. Basicamente, a promise é usada para obter um valor "em outra linha do tempo", portanto, você só vai conseguir obter o valor  dentro do `then`. Para resolver isso, você pode utilizar funções de callback para trabalhar em cima de `docRef.id`.